# The program 'bundle' is currently not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

while i was trying to run this code "bundle install --without production"
I am getting an error like 
"The program 'bundle' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler
"
I have installed bundle already but still getting this error.

This problem occurred while i was learning from Harlt's.."Updating Gemfile" at Heroku setup section

Comment: does `gem install bundler` help?

Comment: @tessi Yes,I have installed bundler through this command..but still getting the same response

Comment: are you using rvm? there might be a conflict between ruby versions.

Comment: @Miotsu Yes i am using rvm ..but there is only one version of ruby(ruby 2.0.0p247)

Comment: If you've installed Ruby through rbenv you might need to run `rbenv rehash` to make it work.

Comment: @Eifion No, I have installed ruby using rvm

Comment: @Eifion Thank you guys..I have resolved my problem accidently but still its beyond my understanding..I have only one version of ruby(ruby 2.0.0) and at the starting of installation i have  run this command "rvm use 2.0.0" and again at this point i have done the same and it solves my problem i really don't know how and why..but now "bundle install -without production" command is working.thank a lot mates

Comment: The error is because you have to tell rvm which ruby is your default, unless you do this you don't are using ruby 2.0 always, to definitely fix the problem ```rvm use 2.0.0 --default```

Comment: @rderoldan1 I have one more issue like.whenever i close command prompt after that if i want to again start working on rails..then before i have to run this command /bin/bash --login and after this command only i can able to use rvm or gem or bundle command..can you suggest some solution to this problem

Comment: The problem is there after `rvm use 2.0.0 --default`, if you only run the use command, your OS use this ruby in your terminal session

Comment: @SandipMondal Thanks to you Now i am getting a new error -:command not found continuously ..please don't give this advice to others..it has created problems for many..cd rails_projects
–: command not found
–: command not found
–: command not found
this what i get after executing the command suggested by you..and now i am not able run even a single command in my Terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First Set up the PATH variable for the installed ruby executable(Suppose the installed ruby is ruby-2.0.0-p451):

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin
```

and then run,

`gem install bundler` (if bundler is not installed)

and lastly run,

`rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p451 --default` (--default is optional).

There you go. Now you would be able to run `bundle` command with out any issues.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I did have bundler installed, but it was not setup in my PATH variable.  Quickly adding the right path in my .bashrc solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For those, who uses **rbenv** receipt is:

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
bundle
```