# Error: -:Command not found, After running command "echo 'rvm_path="$HOME/.rvm"' >> ~/.rvmrc –"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, command-prompt, rvmrc

I am getting this error after i have executed this command

`"echo 'rvm_path="$HOME/.rvm"' >> ~/.rvmrc –".`.

As suggested by someone in this forum.[The program 'bundle' is currently not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897450/the-program-bundle-is-currently-not-installed?noredirect=1#comment27957879_18897450)
and now ,Even i try to change the directory it is showing like

```
-:command not found
-:command not found
-:command not found
-:command not found
```

.I don't know what happened but before this,i was using rails by logging through /bin/bash --login command but now i am getting this error.

```
 abhinay@abhinay-Pc:~$ rvm -v
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found
    /home/abhinay/.rvmrc: line 1: $'\342\200\223': command not found

rvm 1.22.10 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

abhinay@abhinay-Pc:~$ cd rails_projects
–: command not found
–: command not found
–: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the file:

```
rm -f /home/abhinay/.rvmrc
```

rvm will work just fine without it, additionally it is not required to force `rvm_path` - rvm does great job detecting it - especially as the `$HOME/.rvm` - is the default

Comment: thanks soo much it really worked .but i would like to know that why it is required to login into bash ("/bin/bash --login") everytime i open a new terminal to run rvm or rails commands..this was the reason i have gone for random solution so that i don't have to login everytime .

Comment: you can set your terminal to use login shell, see this for example: http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal - it is required to login because rvm prints outputs (like warnings) in some  situations that would break processes (scp, X server).